# Laravel getting data from a deep relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many, laravel-7

I have 3 tables:

| Users | Baskets | Items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
|  | user_id | basket_id |
|  |  | price |

I'm trying setup a relationship in eloquent by which I can get all the all the Items and the corresponding Baskets where the price of items is X. I want it so that I can simply use $user->items(x) and get the results.

I'm unsure if this can be done using Relationships alone or will I have to resort to writing custom queries.

Any, and all, help and guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: Its long time i used laravel and can't remebwr exactly the function names, but what i remeber is that you should have a relation ship based between users and baskets, get the relation ship where user_id in baskets is equal to user_id in users and after that you can do relation ship between items and baskets since now you will have only one level relation ship after the first step, hope a helped you . Good luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `hasManyThrough` Define the relationship in your models:

**User Model**

```
 /**
 * Get all of the items & baskets for the user.
 */
 public function items($price)
 {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Items', 'App\Baskets')
        ->with('basket')
        ->where('price',$price);
 }
```

**Basket Model**

```
 /**
 * Get the Items's Basket.
 */
 public function basket()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Basket','basket_id');
 }
```

And then call it like this:

```
 $user->items(x);
```

This will return all user items with their corresponding baskets in a specific price.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship you are looking for is `hasManyThrough`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

**User Modal**

```php
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Item::class, Bucket::class);
}
```

The way you want to use is not possible to achieve I think.

**Possible Usage**

```php
$user->items()->where('price', x);
```

of if you define custom scopes

**Item Modal**

```php
public function scopeWherePrice($query, $value)
{
    return $query->where('price', $value);
}
```

**Usage**

```php
$user->items()->wherePrice(x);
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to write a code like `$user->items(x)` you can define a method on the `User Modal`.

Note that this is not a relationship, just another method which fetch the result.

**User Modal**

```php
public function items($price)
{
    return this->items()->where('price', $price)->get();
}
```